# What does manifest or manifesting mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, slang

I found in my research manifest means "showing someone the facts about something/to make clear or evident to the eye or the understanding/to show something clearly, through signs or actions". But in Tiktok and Twitter this word manifesting is completely different. They likely to mean "to hope for a desire until it comes true". Maybe the word manifesting they use is a gen z word. I want some example for both word to understand these words clearly. Thank you

Comment: [Chambers Dictionary](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=manifest&title=21st) shows a range of definitions. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manifest) gives a lot of example usage. Which dictionary are you using to research?

Comment: Well, that **is** what happens in new communication media -- words change meaning much faster than pronunciation. We're the wrong kinda media here; you need to check with Twiktok, etc.

Comment: It is confusing that you are asking for examples of this usage. If you haven't already seen some examples of it, how do you know that it exists?

Comment: My native language is not English. I think I failed in making my points clear. I thought I would get my answers here, but what I am getting is- only questions! Anyway I want to delete my question, I would be greatful if anyone helps me to find out the delete option. I only can see here edit option, no delete option.

Comment: Anna, you can't ask about meanings like this re digital media without examples. In any event, what you say just doesn't sound right to me,

Answer (score 1):

This modern usage is documented in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=manifest):

> Made it happen, made something real, wished for something and it ended up happening
> *I always wanted a dog, I manifested it and finally I have a dog now!*

I suspect it may be derived from this definition of the adjective, described in [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/manifest)

> *Psychoanalysis*. of or relating to conscious feelings, ideas, and impulses that contain repressed psychic material